# Help with discrete math problem, finding all exponents.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If I have the following equation

$$2^a \times f(x) \leq 4 \times 3^b$$

Where $a = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, $b = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ and $f(x)$ is a diophantine function. $x = 1, 2, 3, /dots$, $f(x)$ may be positive, negative, or $0$. Though I think $f(x)$ will be mostly irrelevant for what I'm doing.

I'm going to rearrange the equation by dividing out the $2^a$, this gives us

$$f(x) \leq 2^{2 - a} \times 3^b$$

Now I know that $f(x)$ will be an integer, and can technically be negative, so I'm going to say that it has to be greater than some $k \times 3^b$, for some value of $k$.
Then I get

$$k \times 3^b \leq f(x) \leq 2^{2-a} \times 3^b$$

Or in other words

$$ k \times 3^b \leq 2^{2-a} \times 3^b$$

Canceling out the $3^b$ gives us

$$k \leq 2^{2-a}$$

I can solve this for a like so.

$$ln(k) \leq ln(2^{2-a})$$

$$ln(k) \leq (2-a) ln(2)$$

$$\frac{ln(k)}{ln(2)} \leq 2-a$$

And lastly

$$a \leq 2 - \frac{ln(k)}{ln(2)}$$

Now we know that $a = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ so that means that the lowest value that $a$ can take is $1$.
Thus

$$1 \leq 2 - \frac{ln(k)}{ln(2)}$$

Solving this for $k$ again gives us

$$\frac{ln(k)}{ln(2)} \leq 1$$

$$ln(k) \leq ln(2)$$

And finally

$$k \leq 2$$

We also know that from $a \leq 2 - \frac{ln(k)}{ln(2)}$, that in order to keep a positive and real, $k > 0$

Then $k = 1$ or $k = 2$.

Plugging in $k=1$ into the equation for a gives us

$$a \leq 2 - \frac{ln(1)}{ln(2)}$$

But $ln(1) = 0$, so

$$a \leq 2$$

If we plugging in $k=2$, the fraction cancels to $1$ and we get

$$a \leq 1$$

This is included in the first response so then $a = 1$ or $a = 2$.

Does this math all check out? Did I do this right? Have I made any errors and if so where?

Thanks again!